# Ajax post json body getting status 0

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

When i am trying to post data to url, i am getting status 0 error. it is working fine in postman. can any one suggest me why i am getting this.

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var d = JSON.stringify({"abc": "123"});
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: d,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        alert("Succeeded");
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
     alert("Fail"+JSON.stringify(jqXHR)+JSON.stringify(textStatus)+errorThrown);
  },
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'added dummy url in stackoverflow'
});
    });


});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Get Result</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Please see the changes ........

$(document).ready(function(){
var d = JSON.stringify({"abc": "123"});
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
    contentType: 'application/json',
    **type: 'POST',
    url: 'added dummy url in stackoverflow'
    data: {d:d},**
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        alert("Succeeded");
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
     alert("Fail"+JSON.stringify(jqXHR)+JSON.stringify(textStatus)+errorThrown);
  },

});
    });


});
```